# How to reset validation after submitting a form in AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs

I have one input field:

```
<input type="text" name="title" ng-model="genreData.title" class="form-control"
        ng-class="{'error': addGenreForm.title.$invalid && !addGenreForm.title.$pristine}"
       placeholder="Genre name" ng-minlength="minlength" required autofocus>
```

When I succesfully submit form this input is got `class="error"` after this:

```
$scope.genreData = {};
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: Could you share the function which submits the form? A pseudo code could be fine.

Comment: please add the controller code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got to inject the form in the `ng-submit` function and then call the form's controller built in function `$setPristine()`.

e.g.

View:

```
<form name="myForm" ng-submit="submitForm(myForm)">
   <!--Input Fields-->
</form>
```

Controller:

```
$scope.submitForm = function(form) {
   //Do what ever I have to do
   //Then reset form
   form.$setPristine();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think setting

`$scope.addGenreForm.$setPristine() and $scope.addGenreForm.$setUntouched`

can work after submitting your form

Please share some plunker so I can help more if you still have any issues

Comment: Where to add this?

Comment: in your submmitform() function, after you have successfully submitted form